# Discriminated union structural/custom equality

Tags: f#, discriminated-union

I have the following discriminated union:

```
type ActCard = Cellar of card list 
                | Chapel of (card option * card option* card option* card option) 
                | Smithy | Spy of (card -> bool * card -> bool)
```

It had structural equality until I added the `card -> bool` to `Spy`. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10957528/structural-equality-in-f) is helpful for how to do custom equality for records. However, I'm not sure how best to implement it in this situation. I would prefer to not have to enumerate each case in `ActCard`:

```
override x.Equals(yobj) =
    match x, yobj with
    |  Spy _, Spy _ -> true
    |  Cellar cards, Cellar cards2 -> cards = cards2
    (* ... etc *)
```

What is a better approach here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There isn't a better approach. If you're not going to use the default structural equality you'll have to spell out equality semantics.

#### EDIT

You *could* do something like this.

```
[<CustomEquality; CustomComparison>]
type SpyFunc = 
  | SpyFunc of (card -> bool * card -> bool) 
  override x.Equals(y) = (match y with :? SpyFunc -> true | _ -> false)
  override x.GetHashCode() = 0
  interface System.IComparable with
    member x.CompareTo(y) = (match y with :? SpyFunc -> 0 | _ -> failwith "wrong type")

type ActCard = 
  | Cellar of card list 
  | Chapel of (card option * card option * card option * card option) 
  | Smithy 
  | Spy of SpyFunc
```

Comment: What if I want ActCard to support comparison? Is it necessary to provide a comparison for `SpyFunc`?

Comment: Yes. You'll need to use the `CustomComparison` attribute and implement `System.IComparable`. I updated my answer to demonstrate.

Comment: Excellent, thanks. How can you apply those attributes to a type when it's part of an `and` binding?

Comment: Put the attributes after `and`. For example, `type A() = class end and [<CustomEquality; CustomComparison>] B() = class end`.